# Command to go to previous folder in cent os

Tags: centos-5

Suppose I have entered following sequence of command:

```
[root@user ~] cd /
[root@user /] cd /usr
[root@user usr] cd /local
[root@user local] cd /myFolder
[root@user myFolder] cd /
[root@user /] <!-- do some opration -->
[root@user /] <!-- what can I write to go back to myFolder -->
```

Is there any command in cent os to go back to previous location? That I'm in myFolder then I come back to `/`. Do some operation and then want to go back to myFolder. I'm not talking about writing `cd /usr/local/myFolder`. May be there is something like `back` or `backto_previous_location`. I want functionality something like we get by clicking on Back button in window explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions:

- The most powerful one: Use the [Bash directory stack](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Directory-Stack)
- Somewhat what you are looking for: `cd -` which goes to the PWD *before* the last `cd`. In fact, the `cd -`  command is equivalent to `cd "$OLDPWD"` - I think that you can guess what `$OLDPWD` is. More information [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables).

Comment: `cd -` works fine. Thnx.

Comment: its work like just copy adsress you need   [root@pgadmin nodejs-simple-file-upload]# cd -
/home/sirmagid/public_html/digipaz/node_modules/nodejs-simple-file-upload/uploads

Answer (score -1):

to go previous dirctory you just type

## cd Desktop

Desktop # cd test
Desktop/test#cd love
Desktop/test/love# cd ../ test
Desktop#